# Reason for getting -10(says user removed).

Tags: discussion

Recently i answered a question on SFSE link [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213173/where-to-start-with-salesforce/213174#213174) . My answer got down-voted twice which i completely get since i did not  do enough diligence to mark it as duplicate.

I got excited by seeing someone with similar experience to me trying to learn salesforce and replied instantly.

What i did not understand was i lost 10 points saying user removed. My intention is not to fight for these 10 points but to understand why it happened so that i dont run into the same problem again.

[image]

Any clarity or clarification would help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means exactly what it says. A user was removed, and their votes were invalidated. This particular user gave you one upvote on an answer, or two on questions.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, i checked and did not see any up-vote i guess because the user was removed i was not able to see that. thanks for the clarification.